# What is this called? Is this a design pattern or a convention? (Interfaces / classes)

Tags: java, oop, interface

Lately when I have been looking at other code, I have noticed that I see one file with multiple interfaces and classes - sometimes extending those interfaces.

What is this called? Is this good / bad practice?

Also, if it is good practice, is there any documentation on how to properly utilize this? If not, is there some other documentation on using interfaces most efficient and the 'best practices' for them?

One place they are used is here: [Google IoSched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/provider/ScheduleContract.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term for a class that is a member of another class is a [*nested class*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). As the tutorial explains, this is done for several reasons:

- It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place.
- It increases encapsulation.
- Nested classes can lead to more readable and maintainable code.

This technique is often used when the nested class is closely tied to the enclosing class. (For instance, [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) is a nested class of [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and [Character.UnicodeBlock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html) is a nested class of [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).)

Nested interfaces serve the same function—to define an interface that is closely connected to the enclosing class.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like [enums using interfaces pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface) (or rather anti-pattern now).  Now that Java has [enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) and [static imports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) there is no reason to use this.

Answer (score 2):

They're inner (nested) classes/interfaces, used when the classes or interfaces make no sense without the containing class or are generally accessed only by the containing class, or in a context tightly coupled to the containing class.

They exist in JSE as well, e.g., [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html).

Answer (score 0):

These are inner interfaces (which are inherently static inner interfaces, even though they aren't explicitly marked with the modifier `static`. They are used to define an interface that is so closely connected to the class it's defined within that it wouldn't be worthwhile defining it outside that class.